# Too much JSON crashes browser :(

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an ajax country/city selector. When I select United States the browser crashes. Doh!

I have a dropdown list of countries. When I select a country a jQuery ajax call is run which gets a JSON response of cities belonging to that country.

I should have seen it coming when I had to increase my allowed memory during execution. Here's the JSON response from selecting the UK.

```
{"5947":"Aberdeen","12838":"Aberystwyth","15707":"Aldershot","18575":"Alsagers Bank","18682":"Altrincham","4863":"Andover","41802":"AOL","6471":"Armagh","18945":"Ascot","4864":"Ashby-de-la-Zouch","4865":"Ashford","5948":"Aviemore","12985":"Aylesbury","12281":"Ballymena","14446":"Banbury","12445":"Bangor","13631":"Barking","4866":"Barnet","17004":"Barnsley","16423":"Barrow-in-Furness","16254":"Basildon","12402":"Basingstoke","5826":"Bath","13289":"Beddgelert","15082":"Bedford","4868":"Belfast","4869":"Belper","13874":"Benfleet","5827":"Benson","15514":"Berkhamsted","4870":"Berwick Upon Tweed","12948":"Betws-y-Coed","18776":"Bexley","14530":"Bicester","4871":"Billericay","18436":"Birkenhead","4872":"Birmingham","14592":"Blackburn","14686":"Blackpool","12526":"Bolton","12480":"Bournemouth","13062":"Bracknell","18772":"Bradford","4873":"Braemar","4874":"Brecon","4875":"Brentwood","18820":"Brighton","14260":"Bristol","4876":"Broomfield","42004":"Burgess Hill","14654":"Burnley","4877":"Burton Upon Tren","13812":"Bury","15835":"Bury St Edmunds","16500":"Camberley","4878":"Cambridge","4879":"Canterbury","5957":"Cardiff","14443":"Carlisle","14065":"Carrickfergus","42384":"Chalgrove","5832":"Chatham","13641":"Chelmsford","4880":"Cheltenham","4881":"Chester","42879":"Chesterfield","12160":"Chichester","41768":"Chorley","14056":"Church Stretton","5949":"Cladich","4884":"Colchester","16204":"Congleton","17534":"Coniston","42888":"Corsham","4885":"Coventry","13575":"Crawley","15410":"Crewe","13913":"Croydon","4886":"Cumbernauld","13711":"Dartford","4887":"Dartmouth","5833":"Derby","17468":"Derry","4889":"Doncaster","13696":"Dorchester","15377":"Dorking","5834":"Dover","16659":"Dudley","41867":"Dumbarton","18091":"Dumfries","4890":"Dunbar","14217":"Dunblane","4891":"Dundee","14067":"Dunfermline","4892":"Durham","16058":"East Molesey","17521":"East Preston","12501":"Eastbourne","12374":"Eastrea","4893":"Edinburgh","18992":"Elgin","41763":"Ellesmere","12883":"Ely","16825":"Enfield","14510":"Epsom","5835":"Exeter","4894":"Falkirk","5836":"Falmouth","42388":"Faringdon","42034":"Farmington","14604":"Farnham","42347":"Feltham","12829":"Fleet","4895":"Forres","42315":"Frosterley","5950":"Glasgow","4896":"Glastonbury","12562":"Gloucester","15956":"Gosport","4898":"Grangemouth","12626":"Gravesend","16057":"Grays","4899":"Great Wilbraham","4900":"Greenock","12752":"Grimsby","11747":"Guildford","14506":"Guilford","11938":"Halifax","5010":"Hamilton","15553":"Harlow","41733":"Harpenden","14713":"Harrow","4902":"Hartlepool","18952":"Haslemere","13977":"Hastings","14917":"Hatfield","12529":"Haverfordwest","4903":"Haverhill","4904":"Hawarden","5951":"Hawick","11776":"Hemel Hempstead","15302":"Hereford","14999":"Hertford","41893":"Heston","16056":"Hexham","13019":"High Wycombe","13643":"Hoddesdon","5958":"Holyhead","12420":"Hornchurch","14160":"Horsham","12108":"Huddersfield","5837":"Hull End","13296":"Huntingdon","14801":"Hyde","17707":"Ilford","41721":"Inverkeithing","4905":"Inverness","5838":"Ipswich","4906":"Keighley","4907":"Kelso","18628":"Kendal","17805":"Kenilworth","4908":"Kennet","4909":"Kettering","18578":"Kidsgrove","18984":"Kilmarnock","4910":"Kingston Upon Hull","5952":"Kirkwall","18257":"Lakenheath","15425":"Lampeter","13182":"Lancaster","4911":"Laughton","13488":"Leamington","18824":"Leeds","13135":"Leek","17849":"Leicester","17716":"Leigh","12836":"Lerwick","13387":"Letchworth","4912":"Lewes","41767":"Leyland","13546":"Lichfield","5840":"Lincoln","19039":"Little Chalfont","16778":"Liverpool","13442":"Llandrindod Well","5953":"Loch Ness","12008":"London","15035":"Loughborough","15518":"Loughgall","15011":"Louth","18492":"Lowestoft","14023":"Luton","4913":"Machynlleth","12416":"Maidenhead","12230":"Maidstone","14722":"Manchester","4914":"Mansfield","4915":"Margate","4916":"Marlborough","17889":"Marlow","18870":"Melborne","16170":"Melton Mowbray","4917":"Merton","5844":"Middlesbrough","5959":"Milford","15181":"Millom","12315":"Milton Keynes","12089":"Mold","18816":"Montrose","5954":"Motherwell","18574":"Nantwich","4918":"Newark","17097":"Newbury","5845":"Newcastle","4919":"Newcastle Upon Tyne","19040":"Newport","41682":"Newquay","13629":"Northallerton","4922":"Northampton","18577":"Northwich","42209":"northwold","15080":"Norwich","5847":"Nottingham","4923":"Oban","11975":"Oldham","6474":"Omagh","17161":"Oxford","15422":"Oxshott","18627":"Penrith","4925":"Penzance","16404":"Perth","5848":"Peterborough","4926":"Plains","4927":"Plymouth","15551":"Pontypridd","14208":"Poole","4928":"Portsmouth","17642":"Portstewart","41766":"Preston","5011":"Prestwick","18579":"Radway Green","42069":"Ramsgate","11775":"Reading","14706":"Redditch","16276":"Ringwood","15522":"Ripon","14673":"Rochester","15968":"Romford","41857":"Rugby","15289":"Runcorn","17520":"Rustington","14052":"Saint Albans","16462":"Salford","4931":"Salisbury","42295":"Sandwich","17690":"Sandy","4932":"Scarborough","13975":"Seaford","12003":"Shaftesbury","18891":"Sheffield","5850":"Shrewsbury","13178":"Slough","14708":"Solihull","4935":"Southampton","4936":"Southborough","14524":"Southend-on-Sea","13970":"Southport","42260":"St Albans","5955":"St Andrews","15841":"St Asaph","18576":"St Helens","16114":"St Ives","12717":"Stafford","41746":"Staines","14051":"Stanmore","16656":"Stansted","42032":"Stevenage","5012":"Stirling","11801":"Stockport","14198":"Stockton-on-Tees","4937":"Stoke On Trent","42386":"Stranraer","4938":"Stratford-Upon-Avon","4939":"Stroud","18615":"Sudbury","11860":"Sunderland","16393":"Sutton","5960":"Swansea","12853":"Swindon","4941":"Taunton","5851":"Teeside","13973":"Telford","4943":"Truro","17702":"Virginia Water","5852":"Waddington","12059":"Wakefield","4945":"Wallingford","4947":"Wareham","5853":"Warrington","4948":"Warwick","4949":"Watford","12009":"Wellingborough","12528":"Wellington","13366":"Wells","12530":"Welwyn Garden City","16785":"Weston Under Lizard","16334":"Wetherby","18171":"Weymouth","4950":"Whitby","13308":"Whitehaven","42387":"Whitehead","5956":"Wick","17581":"Wilmslow","5854":"Wimbledon","12524":"Wimborne Minster","12551":"Winchester","15946":"Windsor","18573":"Winsford","4952":"Wisbech","4953":"Wisborough Green","12982":"Woking","18769":"Wokingham","13287":"Wolverhampton","17904":"Woodford","18086":"Woolavington","11783":"Worcester","12128":"Worthing","5961":"Wrexham","13630":"Yarm","17015":"Yeovil","11824":"York"}
```

Here is my Javascipt:

```
$('#current-country').change(function(){ //any select change on the dropdown with id country trigger this code
            $('.select-current-city').show();
            $("#current-cities > option").remove(); //first of all clear select items
            var country_id = $('#current-country').val();  // here we are taking country id of the selected one.
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url()?>map/get_cities/"+country_id, //here we are calling our user controller and get_cities method with the country_id

                success: function(cities) //we're calling the response json array 'cities'
                {
                    $.each(cities,function(id,city) //here we're doing a foeach loop round each city with id as the key and city as the value
                    {
                        var opt = $('<option />'); // here we're creating a new select option with for each city
                        opt.val(id);
                        opt.text(city);
                        $('#current-cities').append(opt); //here we will append these new select options to a dropdown with the id 'cities'
                    });
                }

            });

        });
```

Has anyone any suggestions on how I can process this much data in the browser?

I'm using PHP (Codeigniter), MySQL and jQuery.

Comment: How much data? What's the size of the HTTP-response? (Check the network tab in your browser developer tools)

Comment: That's only 6K.  Even IE could handle that!  Your problem lies elsewhere

Comment: that is not that much data - are you sure the problem is retrieving the response and not processing it? If this was too large to receive your browser wouldn't crash - it would hang. Lastly - you forgot to mention which browser you are seeing this in.

Comment: If you use an autocomplete box instead of a drop down, you could defer the call back until 2 or 3 letters have been typed and greatly reduce the list size.

Comment: Yeah that's a huge list for America.  Do you really need to return the entire list of USA cities?  Can't the user specify even the state and return just the states cities?

Comment: Telerik has a feature called LoadOnDemand for dropdowns, perhaps you could work on an implementation for this in your javascript. The feature loads a specified number of records at the time, same as a paging on the server kind of thing. So you can load, say 40 cities, and when the user scrolls or types, you have it make another request to the server either bringing the next batch of records or doing a search based on user input.. not a couple hours solution, but that could work for you

Comment: Don't do redundant DOM selection in a loop. `$('#current-cities').append(opt);`

Comment: And create your options like this: `$('<option />',{val:id,text:city})`. jQuery has some optimizations for this form.

Comment: Also consider caching a set of options for a country instead of just destroying and then recreating them if the country is selected again. Or at least cache the parsed JSON.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback, particularly chris lol. I've changed it from being a dropdown to a autotcomplete textbox with the city and country name concatenated into a string. Works really well. Should of done it from the start. Thanks Andrew. If you create an answer out of your comment i'd happily mark it as correct since it's helped me fix my issue

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend creating an array of your new `option` nodes, and then appending them *en masse*.  Doing them one at a time may be what's killing you.

```
var newOptions = [];
$.each(cities,function(id,city)    {
     var opt = $('<option />', { "val": id, "text": city }); 
     newOptions.push(opt[0]);  //need to push actual dom node - thanks RightSaidFred
});

$('#current-cities').append(newOptions);
```

Or should this be clearing previous options in the dropdown?  If so:

```
$('#current-cities').html(newOptions);
```

Comment: You can't use `.join()` like that. You'll end up with `"[object Object][object Object][object Object]..."`

Comment: @RightSaidFred - just realized that - looks like the answer might be *less* jQuery :)

Comment: You could do it the way you were, but you'd just need to push the native DOM element into the Array, and then skip the `.join()`. If jQuery receives an Array, it'll populate the jQuery object with its content. Or you could do `var newOptions = $();`, then `newOptions.push(...)`, though `.push()` isn't officially supported.

Comment: @RightSaidFred - I tried it that way, but no.  `$(DD).append(arrayOfDomNodes);` gives an error of `Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8 `

Comment: @RightSaidFred - thanks.  I'll have to look at PushStack.  Your previous comment cleared things up for me, and led to the most recent edit.

Comment: +1 Just one nitpick. Do `opt[0]` instead of `$(opt)[0]` since `opt` is already a jQuery object.

Comment: pushStack just creates a new jQuery object every time plus it's internal and thus subject to change. Bad idea.

Comment: @RightSaidFred - not a nitpick at all.  Thank you.

Comment: @Esailija: `pushStack` is part of the public API, see the link I provided, and I meant it could be used in the form of passing it a complete Array. Not repeatedly in the loop.

Comment: @RightSaidFred, it's internal as your link says: `Categories: Internals`. And all you need to do here is just a massive string with a single append anyway, not create 2 objects per loop.

Comment: @Esailija - a big string would certainly work, I just think the current code is a bit cleaner than doing string concats in the loop.

Comment: @Esailija: Yes, but that's [a category](http://api.jquery.com/category/internals/). That doesn't mean it's for internal use only like you'll find elsewhere throughout the jQuery source: Like [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6.2/src/core.js#L294), and [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6.2/src/core.js#L603). And a big string would work, but you need to be careful how you create it. Older versions of IE have memory issues with string concatenation.

Comment: @RightSaidFred, that doesn't mean anything. There are millions of stuff in jQuery that is internal and doesn't say anything about internal use only, yet if you depended on those you would be looking at a rewrite at every jQuery release. Arguably pushStack hasn't changed in a while but it's a matter of principle.

Comment: @Esailija: Dude, I'm not saying that everything internal needs to be marked as internal. I'm saying that everything in the API documentation is, well, part of the API. At least it would be entirely foolish for them to include in public API documentation something that isn't meant to be part of the public API.

Comment: @Esailija: If you're interested, I [filed a documentation bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10930) to clarify the intention of the *"Internals"* category.

Comment: @RightSaidFred, thanks, the response there really clarified it. But yeah the catogory name they chose for it is really stupid since it's not "internals" if it's public :D

Answer (score 0):

First double check you are not making the same AJAX request more than once.

A quick and easy solution would be to split your AJAX requests in more than one. Start by dividing it into two, and if that still isn't enough, divide them by 3 or more.

You can then check which JSON size is the right one for you, and use that one. Or you can have your php determine how much requests are needed based on the number of total cities.

For really large lists, I had to split the requests into 100 items each. The first request I would get the first piece of list along with a bit of data indicating how much requests I had to make to obtain the full list, append the new nodes, then I would make the remaining requests, until I got the full list.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how that would crash for you. Here I am doing the worst possible thing and it is blazing fast:

http://jsfiddle.net/HZnYQ/

Each time you select something, I remove all elements one by one and then append them one by one, and it's still instant. Actually my CPU doesn't even make a note of it.